# How can I achieve the gradient used in making the Xbox 360 interface background in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, gradient, background

I just can't figure out how to make a gradient look like the one used on the Xbox 360 interface, that gradient give an effect of an overhead spotlight lighting the menu elements and I want to use that effect in my conceptions, any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a white background **I would add a new Solid color fill/adjustment layer** (by clicking the half filled-in circle at the bottom of your layers panel).

**Then choose a dark color** (for example match the darkest part of the xbox dashboard).

**Select the mask thumbnail of your new fill layer** (the image on the right of your fill layer thumbnail, it appears completely white)

**Now using the eraser tool, select a fairly large and soft edged brush and set the "flow" low** (per my example below I used a flow of 25%)

**Carefully erase from your mask layer revealing the white below.** The more you erase a portion of the mask the more white is revealed.

I did this in a matter of minutes, see below:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was very nice of you but  "condor" didn't even try to figure it out. Didn't know this was a straight up tutorial site. That's just lazy.

Comment: Just here to help haha Didn't take long though, so it was no problem.

Answer (score -2):

I'd make an ellipse and then put a gradient on that ellipse from messing around with the colors and make sure the gradient is set to ellipse